# Unnecessary port number value is appended while running the application in server

Tags: grails

When I run my application in server my home page loads properly with the URL in the format given below. https://server001.suraj.com/jobs. But when I click Add button in my home page then the url changes to the format like, https://server001.suraj.com:8445/jobs/create. I tried to figure out where the value 8445 is appended from but not able to find it out. Can any one suggest me how this value gets appended? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this url load properly? `https://server001.suraj.com:8445/jobs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding this:

```
grails.server.port.https = 443
```

to `BuildConfig.groovy`